# Приведение знаковых и беззнаковых типов в си

Tags: c, типы-данных, unsigned

У меня есть вот такое выражение.

```
uint8_t a = 0 - (0x10+0x38+0x00+0x00+0x5C+0xC0+0x00+0x00+0x8F+0xC0+0x00+0x00+0x73+0xC0+0x00+0x00+0x71+0xC0+0x00+0x00);
```

Мне требуется посчитать контрольную сумму для intlHEX и оно взято из примера.

Результатом данного выражения является 249. Каким образом тут получается 249, по какому правилу отрицательное число приводится к беззнаковом ? Результат сложения всех чисел в скобке 1303, если убрать вычитание из нуля будет 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение берется по модулю 256 (или, в общем случае, 2<sup>n</sup>).

Грубо говоря, к числу прибавляется или вычитается 256 до тех пор, пока оно не окажется в диапазоне 0..255.

> Результатом данного выражения является 249

Запустил у себя, получил `233`. На калькуляторе тоже выходит `233`.

> если убрать вычитание из нуля будет 23.

Это совпало.